# Expected value question, with states!

Tags: probability

Suppose an light can emit 4 different colors of light. The light starts off by emitting blue light. Each second, the color of the light changes according to the following probabilities-

When the light is blue, the next second, the light is red.(Named blue light state 0)

When the light is red, the next second, there is a 1/3 probability of the light being blue, and a 2/3 probability of the light being green.(Named red light state 1)

When the light is green, the next scond, there is a 1/2 probability of the light turning red, and a 1/2 probability of the light turning yellow.(Named green light state 2)

When the light is yellow, the next second, there is a 2/3 probability of the light turning green, and a 1/3 probability of the light turning off.(Named yellw light state 3)

### What is the expected number of seconds it takes for the light to turn off?

Recursion was my attempt in solving this problem. Gave variables L_0, L_1, L_2, and L_3 as expected values for each state of the light. Figured L_1=L_0-1.

---

Nevermind, I think I solved part of this problem, thanks to the help in the comments.
I got

L_0=L_1+1.

L_1=1+L_2*(2/3)+L_0*(1/3).

L_2=1+L_1*(1/2)+L_3*(1/2).

Comment: Markov chain , with first step analysis, written all over this one. What do you know about these two concepts? Certainly you must know Markov chains for this one.

Comment: I have no idea what a markov chain or what that is.

Comment: Ok, so where did you get this question from?

Comment: Probability textbook

Comment: So you are not learning Markov chains, which is surprising. What is the last thing you learned? Alternately, which chapter (of which book) did this problem appear in?

Comment: a chapter about events with states, such as random walks

Comment: Ah, random walks , just another kind of Markov chain. Do you know conditional probability? (Or, what is your background in probability?) This question is not difficult, but it involves conditional probability.

Comment: yes conditional probability was covered. Recursion was my attempt in solving this problem. Gave variables L_0, L_1, L_2, and L_3 as expected values for each state of the light.

Comment: Great. I think I can answer your question with what you've given me. +1 (and you can add some content of your comments to the post if you feel it is relevant)

Comment: Oh wait, I got another expression for L_1. L_1=1+L_2*(2/3)+L_0*(1/3)

Comment: Thanks, I am adding a more complete answer : just giving a larger overview to others who would have the same question as you from the same background. So I may take more time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110048/discussion-between-user118161-and----).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state space ( call it $S = \{b,r,g,y,o\}$) has five states : four colors, and an off state.

The important thing about a random walk, is its Markovian nature : if, during a random walk, I hit a point $x$ in a state space, any probabilities associated with the future of the random walk will depend *only* on the fact that it is *at* $x$ now, and *not* on *how it reached* $x$ (it's history). In words, the future, *given the present*, is independent of the history.

Another way of saying it (at least in discrete time) : a random walk "renews itself" at every stopping time i.e. if you choose to record the random walk only after some point, then it will look as if the random walk was started from the stop point (that is, we can forget the history of the original random walk and work with the "new" random walk from the point it was at when we started to record).

Now, the concept of first - step analysis uses this well. Basically, imagine you want to find the expected time of some random walk starting at a point $a$ to hit a point $c$. Now, you imagine you went a step ahead : so the point $a$ moved to the point $d$ (with some probability of that happening). Now, to get to $c$, we must move from $d$ to $c$, and we can imagine we are studying the random walk started at $d$ now, and see the expected time to reach $c$.

In other words, the expected time from $a$ to hit $c$, depends only upon the expected time from the *neighbors* of $a$ , to hit $c$. How?

---

Well , let us define $P(x,y)$ as the probability of moving from $x$ to $y$ for $x,y \in S$. Define $f : S \to \mathbb R^+$ by $f(s) = E[inf\{n : X_n = o\} |X_0 = s]$. That is, $f(s)$ is the expected time for the bulb to go off, given that we started at a certain color. It is obvious that $f(o) = 0$.

Now, from the statement I made, $f(s) = 1 + \sum_{t \in S} P(s,t)f(t)$, simply because $s$ must move to some $t$ in the state space (in one second's time), and from there $t$ must move to $o$, so we can imagine we restarted the random walk at $t$. (Of course, note that only $t$ which are neighbours of $s$ will have a non-zero term in the summation above).

This gives, in our case :
$$
f(b) = 1+f(r) \\
f(r) = 1+\frac 13 f(b) + \frac 23 f(g) \\
f(g) = 1 + \frac 12f(r) + \frac 12f(y)\\
f(y) = 1 + \frac 23 f(g) + \frac 13 f(o)\\
f(o)= 0
$$

Can you solve these equations? $f(b)$ is what you need.

> $f(b) = 18, f(r) = 17,f(g) = 15,f(y)=11$. So it takes $18$ seconds on average for the light to switch off.

Comment: Ah, you made the final step. I already got the first three equations, but not the final 2. Thank you.(I defined my states with L_x, instead of f(x)). Didn't think of making L_4, or in your case f(o) a variable.

Comment: Sure, that means we differ in small places, but our idea was the same. You are welcome! You can, of course, verify your answer with me (I've got the answer, I'll post it in a hidden box)